# How to fire custom event for IE(less than 9) elemnts through vbscript

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vbscript

I want to fire custom event through vb-script . I am able to fire custom event through jscript

```
 function customEventFn()
 {
 //function body
 };
 var element = document.getElementById("elem id");
 customEventFn.call(element);
```

But this approach wont work in Vbscript. 
any body have any idea to achieve this in Vbscript

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse me if I'm not familiar with JS terminology and therefore not understand your question right, but what you mean by "*custom event*"? None of both (JS/VBS) has such feature. We can bind a function to `SomeObjectWithEnets.ExistingEventName`, for example:

```
// in JavaScript/JScript
function foo() {
    alert(typeof window.onload); // function
    alert(typeof this);          // object
}
window.onload = foo;

' in VBScript
Sub Foo()
    MsgBox TypeName(Window.OnLoad) 'Object
    MsgBox TypeName(Me)            'HTMLWindow2
End Sub
Set Window.OnLoad = GetRef("Foo")
```

What I know from my poor knowledge of JS is that `someFn.call(obj)` just "inject" (execute) `someFn` into `obj` scope, and all this have nothing about with events. And can you do this in VBScript? I don't think so.

[EDIT] After your second post I see what you mean but doubt is it possible in older IE.

```
' IE9+ -------------- -> IE8- --------------
' addEventListener    -> attachEvent (but deprecated)
' createEvent         -> createEventObject
' initCustomEvent     -> no alternative
' dispatchEvent       -> no alternative (fireEvent?)
' removeEventListener -> detachEvent (removed too)
```

Answer (score 0):

i just want to  fire custom event in IE . i can able to fire custom event in iE9 with following code, but it wont work IE8 or IE7(less than 9 ).

```
Function CustomFunction()
me.value ="samplevalue"
me.color = RED
End Function
set customFn = getRef("CustomFunction")
set element = document.getElementById("elemid");
element.addEventListener "OnSampleEvent", customFn
set Event = document.createEvent("sampleEvent")
Event.initCustomEvent "OnSampleEvent", false, false, nil
element.dispatchEvent(Event)
element.removeEventListener "OnSampleEvent", customFn
```

Is any way achieve this in older version of IE.

Comment: Ok, I see, look at my edited answer, this is the best I can help atm.